# What is the effect of "Make depth sticky" in subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, sticky

I'm having a hard time finding clear documentation on the behavior of using a sticky depth setting on an SVN working copy.  In SVN when using the "Update to Revision" dialog there is a "Make depth sticky" checkbox.

What are the effective differences between making depth sticky and non-sticky?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When the depth is sticky, you'll will update with the same settings each time you update. If the depth isn't sticky, next time you update you will revert back to the former setting, pottentially downloading everything recursively (that is maybe a lot of data).

### EDIT:

It seems that "fully recursive" is currently broken. I need to test more, but the latest version seems to have the problem.

To achieve the effect you want you probably want to use the "Choose items..." dialog and check everything out, then use "Exclude" to avoid bringing in changes for folders you don't want.

Comment: If I'm doing a sparse checkout (children items and folders only) and I perform a full-recursive non-sticky update to a specific child folder will future updates retrieve all changes to that child folder, or will that folder become out of sync with the latest changes over time?

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't work right now on my machine. Forcing fully recursive non sticky doesn't bring in the missing file. I am not up to date though and I'll be checking.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, perhaps a bug in Tortoise 1.7.6 (I just updated on Friday)

Answer (score 0):

It is related with ***Sparse Directory*** checkout and update. Explained in detail [here](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/sparsedirs/).

If you are having problems with ***externals*** download from Sparse Directory you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36914648/378783).