# tortoiseSVN "update to revision" window "Make depth sticky" checkbox how use it?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

tortoiseSVN "update to revision" window "Make depth sticky" checkbox how use it??

now ~ i don't unchecked and checked difference~

what time checked or unchecked .

Comment: Don't know what you mean - can you provide more details and/or screenshots?

Comment: That is to say, "Make the depth sticky" checkbox checked under any circumstances, under what circumstances unchecked? I don't know now "Make the depth sticky" role

Comment: Can use operation steps to teach me?
Such as the:
(1)
(2)
(3)

Simple words I still look at don't understand, operation steps can tell~~

thank all~~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the effect of "Make depth sticky" in subversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667642/what-is-the-effect-of-make-depth-sticky-in-subversion)